# Architectural details of Android VPN service : How tun0 gets created?

Tags: vpn

I would like to know how android creates a VPN tun0 interface. After I call establish from VPNService, Builder, the ServiceManager takes up the process and create the tun0. For that it uses parcels to send to Binder, but I am kind of confused as to what it does after that. I want to understand in detail how an interface gets created.

I have tried using strace on the application to see what kind of system calls get executed, but I did not see any ioctl calls from the application pid, but saw them on the system_Server pid. I understand that system_Server is what creates the interface, but how does Binder talk to system_Server asking to create an interface. Kindly point to any source code . It would be really helpful .

Comment: Is this a user-focused question? Asking for source code makes it rather look like developer-centric. And development questions are off-topic here. They rather belong to our sister site at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a development related question but what I know is that [binder](https://elinux.org/Android_Binder) is inter-process communication [(IPC)](https://www.chandrashekar.info/articles/linux-system-programming/introduction-to-linux-ipc-mechanims.html) mechanism (like [sockets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/what_is_socket.htm)) which processes use by opening `/dev/*binder` character devices. Binder IPC is [used](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc) by Android's Java framework (for JNI communication) as well as native processes (e.g. for communication with vendor's binary blobs).

`tun` is Ethernet-like virtual network interface created by kernel (provided that it's built with [`tuntap`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) support) so that a program can directly read/write IP packets from/to this interface. Creating `tun` needs ioctl `TUNSETIFF` be sent to kernel over `/dev/net/tun` character device (it's `/dev/tun` on Android). Manually you can do:

```
~# ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun
```

Android's VPN service uses `binder` to call native code for `tun` creation.

**RESOURCES:**

- [Android Architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture)
- How AOSP created `tun` interface: [1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/net/VpnService.java#806), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#3710), [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/Vpn.java#1067), [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/services/core/jni/com_android_server_connectivity_Vpn.cpp#65).